# Does the Sonos Port support UPnP?

Tags: sonos

I'm looking at my options to control the Sonos Port at https://developer.sonos.com/reference/. I read about some UPnP control of other Sonos devices, but I can't seem to find any official information about this online. Is UPnP control of the Sonos Port possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sonos uses UPnP for some calls internally, but we never publicly supported this protocol. We encourage you to use the Control API to control Sonos devices. See [Connected Home: Get Started for details](https://developer.sonos.com/). Let us know if you see anything missing that you'd like us to add.

Answer (score 0):

You can control any Sonos device via UPnP. The documentation for this used to be on the musicpartners site but access was exceedingly difficult. much of it is standard UPnP, documented at https://openconnectivity.org/developer/specifications/upnp-resources/upnp/ . There are many open source codebases that use it. It is much more powerful than the documented Cloud API in most regards.